# can @SpringBootTest and @WebMvcTest coexist

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a Test annotated with ;
    @SpringBootTest

and another test calss with @WebMvcTest

and they dont work together, when i move one of them they both work as expected.

Can someone suggest whats the relation/problem with two of them located in one source tree

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` and `@WebMvcTest` should be fine on separate test classes but will not work when used together on the same test class or in the same inheritance hierarchy. Can you please share an example of the setup that does not work and some details of the way in which is does not work?

Answer (score 2):

`@SpringBootTest` loads the whole Spring Context.

`@WebMvcTest` enable you to test, for example, a single `Controller` class.

If you have a full Context available, why would you need `@WebMvcTest`?

And the root cause is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple
>   declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class

Because both annotations `@SpringBootTest` and `@WebMvcTest` have `@BootstrapWith` annotation inside and it's not allowed.

## edit

Answering your comment:
In such situation I'd consider splitting it into two different classes.
Let's assume you want to test `UserController` class. Then you create `UserControllerTest` class for unit tests which is annotated with `@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)` and the second class called `UserControllerIT` which is annotated with `@SpringBootTest` and has a set of integration tests.

Comment: I need to write controller tests, which might not require whole context for example messaging system used underneath, which can be mocked. While i do need another test which loads the whole conetxt and run few tests again

Comment: @ZafarAli Edited my post to answer your doubts

Comment: This is exactly how i started it, but when running these tests both fails, merely due to fact the are in same source tree as i observed

Comment: I do not understand, could u clarify please? Why do they fail